# Android: How to create visual waves/particles like on the image (provided)

Tags: android

[image]

I started creating audio player and I am wondering how can I create visual waves like that? Is there any libraries or classes available?

Answer (score 0):

Use this library. There are samples and lib;
https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer